# virtualization with T2400 cpu, dell d620

Tags: virtualbox

I'm totally lost...

I have a dell d620 with T2400 cpu and I emabled virtualization from bios. The microsoft utility confirms that intel-V is existing and active. However, I cannot install xp 64 bit version on VirtualBox, saying "virtualbox attempting to load an x64 operating system, however this cpu is not compatible with x64 mode"

I need to verify some app in 64 bit mode, can I do something to install some 64 bit os to my notebook?

Or (just a thought) anyone knows if exists some online services for emulation, or remote access to 64 bit machines?

Thanks very much,

Answer (score 3):

The [T2400](http://ark.intel.com/products/27235/Intel-Core-Duo-Processor-T2400-2M-Cache-1_83-GHz-667-MHz-FSB) is not a 64-bit CPU, it cannot run 64-bit operating systems.

Comment: aha, so there is nothing I can do...

Comment: Sadly, there is nothing you can do other than use a 32-bit OS or use a different CPU.